# Eigen map of python memory

Tags: python, ctypes, eigen

I'm trying to optimize some python code by calling a C++ function that does uses eigen.
I'm using ctypes for that. My numpy array is passed in as a float* (Based on this example: https://github.com/nicolamontecchio/ctypes-eigen-numpy)
This works for input arrays, but I'm having trouble with the result.

Basically it looks like this:

```
void some_function(..., int32_t** results) {
    for (int32_t i = 0; ...) {
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::RowVectorXi> eigen_result(results[i], 1, size));

        eigen_result = Eigen::RowVectorXi::Zero(size);
    }
}
```

This works as I can print the output of the function in python. However, at the end of the function, I get the following error:

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
```

This error doesn't occur when doing for example

```
eigen_result(0) = 5.0;
```

So it seems that the assignment isn't really filling in the data into my data pointer. Can someone explain to me how this assignment should happen so the data is actually filled into my pointer without allocating some new pointer that gets freed twice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I miscalculated the `size` variable.
It makes sense this causes memory problems...

Eigen Map works as expected.